# Unable to reverse value for property path "meeting": The choice "340" does not exist or is not unique

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My question is in title. I have had read the same case but doesn't help me.
I want to display a sion click field on a radio button. If a match is made, then there is a fill. If there is no match, then another fill is made in the same field. The latter case is defined in a function, the first case is defined in the controller

My FormType

```
 ->add('meeting', EntityType::class,[

                        'class' => Meeting::class,
                        'choice_label' => function ($meeting) {
                            return 'RDV-'.$meeting->getId() . ' : ' . $meeting->getCompanyName();
                        },

                        'query_builder' => function(MeetingRepository $repository) use ($data) {

                           $date = new DateTimeImmutable( 'now - 420 days');

                                 return $repository->createQueryBuilder('m')
                                     ->where("m.siren = :siren")
                                     ->andWhere('m.commercial = :commercial')
                                     ->andWhere('m.status = 9')
                                     ->andWhere('m.date > :date')
                                     ->setParameters(['siren' => $data['siren'], 'commercial' => $data['commercial'], 'date' => $date]);

                        },
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => 'RDV *',
                        'label_attr' => [
                            'class' => 'form-label',
                        ],

                        'attr' => [
                            'class' => 'js-select form-select',
                            'autocomplete' => "off",
                            'data-hs-tom-select-options' => "{ \"placeholder\": \"Sélectionnez un rendez-vous...\", \"dropup\": true}"
                        ],
                        'row_attr' => [
                            'class' => 'mb-3 col-2 tom-select-custom',
                            'data-hs-validation-validate-class'
                        ],
                    ]);
```

My controller :

```
 let siren = $('#order_odyc_siren').val();
        let commercial = $('#order_odyc_commercial').val();
        let rdvTmkOui = $('#order_odyc_rdvTmk_0');

        let data = $(event.currentTarget).prop('id') === 'order_odyc_rdvTmk_0'
            ? {
                "order_odyc[rdvTmk]": 1,
                "order_odyc[siren]": siren,
                "order_odyc[commercial]": commercial,
                "order_odyc[match]": false
            }
            : ''

        const form = $(event.currentTarget).closest('form');
        $(event.currentTarget).parent().after('<div id="load-rdv-tmk" class="d-inline"><div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm ms-2 text-primary" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>')

        $.ajax({
            "url": form.attr('action'),
            "method": 'POST',
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset:UTF-8"
            },
            "data": data,
            "complete": (function (html) {

                if($('#order_odyc_tmk').length === 0){
                    $('#order_odyc_rdvTmk_0').parent().parent().after($(html.responseText).find('#order_odyc_tmk').parent())
                    $('#order_odyc_tmk').parent().after($(html.responseText).find('#order_odyc_meeting').parent())

                    console.log('Siren : ' + siren + ' et commercial : ' + commercial)
                    SireneV3.getRdvBySirenAndCommercial(siren, commercial, rdvTmkOui);


                }else{
                    $('#order_odyc_tmk').parent().replaceWith($(html.responseText).find('#order_odyc_tmk').parent())
                    $('#order_odyc_meeting').parent().replaceWith($(html.responseText).find('#order_odyc_meeting').parent())

                }

                $('#load-rdv-tmk').remove()

                HSCore.components.HSTomSelect.init('#order_odyc_tmk')
                HSCore.components.HSTomSelect.init('#order_odyc_meeting')

            })
        });
```

In function if field in controller will not print :

```
function valid(){
                       
                        let choice = $('input[name=formRadio]:checked')
                        
                        //window.alert('RDV-' + choice[0].dataset.id + ' : ' + choice[0].dataset.companyname + ' (' + choice[0].dataset.siren + ')')
                        
                        let div = $('<div class="mb-3 col-2 tom-select-custom" data-hs-validation-validate-class><label class="form-label" for="order_odyc_meeting">RDV *</label></div>')

                        let select = $('<select class="js-select form-select" id="order_odyc_meeting" name="order_odyc[meeting]" data-hs-tom-select_option="{ \\\\"placeholder\\\\": \\\\"Sélectionnez un rendez-vous...\\\\", \\\\"dropup\\\\": true}"></select>');
                        let option = $('<option value="'+choice[0].dataset.id+'" selected >RDV-' + choice[0].dataset.id + ' : ' + choice[0].dataset.companyname+'</option>')

                        $(select).append(option)
                        $(div).append(select)

                        //$('#order_odyc_rdvTmk_0').trigger('click');
                        
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            $('#order_odyc_meeting').parent().replaceWith(div)
                            HSCore.components.HSTomSelect.init('#order_odyc_meeting')
                        },250)
                        
                        $('#order_odyc_rdvTmk_0').data('meeting', choice[0].dataset.siren)
           
                        $('#btn_modal_lastMeetings').trigger('click')
                        
                    }
                    
                </script>`

                break;
```